# Reverseproxy Apache configuration is allowing unwanted traffic through the server

Tags: apache, server, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, listen

To allow the access to a specific server not publicly available, we've structured an architecture with a Apache webserver exposed on internet, and we would like to configure it as Reverse Proxy to redirect only some requests to the private server.
This is the piece of httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 5000    
<VirtualHost *:5000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName servername

 ErrorLog /etc/httpd/conf/error.log

#<Location />
# ProxyPass "http://...:5000/"
# ProxyPassReverse "http://...:5000"
# Order allow,deny
# Allow from all
#</Location>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/" "http://...:5000/" interpolate connectiontimeout=30 timeout=12000
#RewriteRule ^(.*) "http://...:5000/$1"
#ProxyPassMatch ^(.*) "http://...:5000/$1"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://...:5000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever we put `Listen 5000` a lot of undesired traffic pass through the server to other servers on Internet.

In the code above the commented lines are some of attempts I've done.

What is wrong in the configuration that is not blocking the server to works as proxy for everything?
Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to deny some paths from being proxied you have to use the "!": here is a link to the documentation explaining how to do it http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass